# Regex Validation only works with one single Character

Tags: java, regex, oop, spring, validation

I want to check if a userInput is free from special characters, here is my code:

```
public class ValidateHelper {

public boolean userInputContainsNoSpecialCharacters(String input){

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z_0-9 ]");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
        boolean b = m.matches();

        if (b)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
}
```

}

This works if I type one character in a textfield -> "a" in the textfield -> the method returns true
"ab" in the textfield -> method returns false.
can somebody help please?
beste regards Daniel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z_0-9 ]+");`

Answer (score 3):

Change `"[a-zA-Z_0-9 ]"` to `"[a-zA-Z_0-9 ]+"`

The + matches "one or more" of that group.

Answer (score 2):

That is because you are using the [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[]`. If you would like to capture a limited amount, any amount or a range of characters you need to modify it.

```
[a-zA-Z_0-9 ]+ //1 or more characters
[a-zA-Z_0-9 ]{1,5} //1 - 5 characters
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following regex:

```
[A-Za-z0-9]+
```

Comment: You forgot the space the OP has in his regex

Answer (score 1):

change your pattern from `[a-zA-Z_0-9 ]` to `^[a-zA-Z_0-9 ]*$` (for 0 or more valid characters) or `^[a-zA-Z_0-9 ]+$` if you want to ensure they enter a value

A `+` indicates 1 or more repetitions.

A `*` indicates 0 or more repetitions.

The `^` and `$` denote the start end of the line respectively.